# Android Studio stuck at installing APK, the adb sometimes fails to install the APK, and somehow Android Studio interferes with adb's install command

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-install-apk

[Some time ago I had trouble with my Huawei P30 and ADB/Android Studio installing APKs.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61318644/1305745) It turned out I was using outdated versions of the libraries/tools. Got it resolved and happily moved on.

Now that my phone has upgraded to Android 10, I'm facing an issue very similar to the one before, but I cannot seem to fix it the same way (by updating libraries). I've tried installing multiple version of each tool, doing a clean install of Android Studio and the Android related tools, but nothing seems to help.

**Android Studio**

The current behavior is that Android Studio generates the APK only to later get indefinitely stuck at the "installing" step. On some small percentage of tests it fails.

**ADB**

I've also tried installing the APK from the command line using `adb`, but I get mixed results.

```
$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.4-6686687
```

While Android Studio is running, installing the app either ends up failing, or hanging indefinitely just like in Android Studio:

```
$ cd .../platform-tools

$ adb start-server
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully

$ adb install C:\...\example.apk
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install C:\...\example.apk

$ adb install C:\...\example.apk
Performing Streamed Install

^^^ Hangs there forever
```

Now, here is where things get interesting, if I close Android Studio, installing the APK results in successful installations about 50% of the time (the other half it fails and restarts the phone connection):

```
$ cd .../platform-tools

$ adb kill-server

$ adb start-server
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully

$ adb install C:\...\example.apk
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install C:\...\example.apk

$ adb kill-server

$ adb start-server
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully

$ adb install C:\...\example.apk
Performing Streamed Install
Success

$ adb kill-server

$ adb install C:\...\example.apk
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
Performing Streamed Install
Success

$ adb kill-server

$ adb install C:\...\example.apk
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
Perform
adb: failed to install C:\...\example.apk
```

I have no trouble performing other actions, like pushing files into the phone or uninstalling apps. So far the issue is only related to installing APKs:

```
$ adb shell pm uninstall com.example
Success

$ adb push C:\...\app-debug.apk /sdcard/APKs
C:\Dropbox...\app-debug.apk: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 15.2 MB/s (31131771 bytes in 1.956s)
```

Why is it that installing an app fails or succeeds as if flipping a coin? Could this be a driver issue? How could Android Studio be interfering with the success rate of running the adb tool separately?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @Prethia not yet, unfortunately.

Comment: In my case, I was waiting for anim complete event of emulator in my jenkins builds, but apparently that wasn't enough. I could consistently install app while I used a sleep statement of 15 minutes which is terrible to say the least, I will post an answer to try to help this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install your application with `./gradlew  installDebug` . It will probably give the reason of the failure

You can also make use of Android's Studio UI:

[image: Gradle UI]

Comment: This is a nice solution! =) Not only is it more reliable than running the `adb` commands manually, but it is quite handy to run from Android Studio's Gradle UI. I did not get any errors, nevertheless I'm finally able to install the app without much trouble. Thanks

Comment: btw, if you have defined flavour. run `./gradlew task` to find out the correct install option

Answer (score 2):

For me it would get stuck at: `Performing Streamed Install` forever.

What fixed it was the old-age answer: unplugging and replugging my USB cable into my phone and then trying again.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by uninstalling the package if it exist on the device:

**Check if the package name of your App exist**

```
$ adb shell dumpsys package com.package.name
```

- if it exist:

```
$ adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.package.name
```

if the uninstall failed then maybe the application is device admin or device owner.

- if it does not exist:

Try changing the install flag of Android studio:
Run > Edit configurations > Install Flags

```
pm install --user 0
```

> Note: the command is `pm install --user 0` without `adb shell`

**Update:**

Let's suppose that the App was never installed on the device.

1. First install

```
adb install myapp.apk
```

The command will succeed and the application will be installed.

2. Second install

```
adb install myapp.apk
```

The command will fail as you already installed a package `com.package.name`

For the second time you install, you should uninstall first:

```
adb uninstall com.package.name
adb install myapp.apk
```

or force to reinstall:

```
adb install -r myapp.apk
```

Comment: The uninstall command is really handy, didn't know about it. Unfortunately the app still fails to be installed after being uninstalled or not being present.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but the install step keeps failing randomly even when the app has been properly uninstalled, even with a force install.

Comment: I've updated my question to be a bit more focused on the important issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabled USB debugging mode and enabling it again on your phone. Sometimes it gets bugged and acts as if its disabled, when its set as enabled

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't have any effect on the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

try update `adb` to latest version

can fix: `adb install xxx.apk` stuck at Performing Streamed Install`

More detail can refer: [android - Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000915/error-adb-exited-with-exit-code-1-performing-streamed-install/65137684#65137684)

Comment: I did try using different versions of the `adb`, as [that resulted to be an issue in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61318644/1305745), but it not solve the issue.

Comment: @cavpollo please try another PC and reinstall adb dicrectly (not use android studio), check whether work or not